# Can I make my own kernel extensions on El Capitan?

Tags: kernel-extensions, macos

I have recently heard that a feature called `rootless` that is going to be on El Capitan. This means that folders such as `/System` cannot be modified by the root user and only signed kext (kernel extensions) can be installed on the computer.

I have not thought about it before but now I have I would like to make my own kext extensions. The only issue is I am not a paid developer so therefor I cannot sign my kext extensions.

When I upgrade to El Capitan would I be able to make by own kexts and install them on my system while still being able to boot my computer and not having to join the $99/Year Apple Developers Program?

Comment: -1 for now - the restrictions on signed kext needs a citation and what are you really trying to do? Is this about how you intend to distribute a kext or just putz with extensions on your development or text rig?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rootless can be completely disabled on OS X El Capitan (though not on iOS, for hopefully obvious reasons). Therefore if you don't mind foregoing the ostensible benefits it provides, you can essentially revert to Yosemite's security model - which is to say, unsigned kexts can be used, but it requires preparation to do so.

It may not be able to be disabled in future versions of the OS, but for now it can be turned off.

Comment: So I just disable it using the command `sudo nvram boot-args="rootless=0";sudo reboot`? Would this compromise my security or not? How necessary is this rootless feature?

Comment: It's not whether disabling Rootless comprises security outright; it's whether the trade offs are worth it. If you don't open unknown email attachments or links, don't visit websites that are likely to try to install malware, only download and install trusted software, etc, it may not affect you. It's another layer of security that each user has to decide for himself if it is necessary in their particular set of circumstances.

Comment: -1 It's not clear whether rootless will be optional, neither on El Capitan nor on any of the following versions.

Comment: There's an entry in the Utilities menu when booting into Recovery (as I understand it) that lets you disable it. [Ars](http://arstechnica.com/apple/2015/06/preview-os-x-el-capitans-first-beta-is-a-promising-heap-of-refinements/4/) has a screenshot of the dialog. Agreed there are no promises it won't become mandatory in the future, but it can be disabled in El Capitan.

Comment: Even if it does become "mandatory", like kext signing in Yosemite, I would be very surprised if there wasn't a way for folks who really wanted to to disable it, again like kext signing in Yosemite.

Comment: Let's be clear: it's optional only in a non-public pre-release. They've never committed to this workaround. They have no incentive to permit unsigned kexts; in fact, they only have a negative incentive.

Comment: I never said they have an incentive to allow unsigned kexts. Yet the option to do so persists, 4 public releases into Yosemite's general availability. As far as rootless, Apple demonstrated how to disable it during a session on security at WWDC. I doubt they'd do that if they weren't intending on leaving it as an option.

Comment: @ChrisHarrington I read that you can disable rootless by running `sudo nvram boot-args="rootless=0";sudo reboot`

Answer (score 2):

Reboot your machine in recovery mode :
hold `cmd+r`

Then launch the terminal and deactivate the *System Integrity Protection status* by entering the following command line :

```
$ csrutil disable
```

This is an unsupported configuration, likely to break in the future and leave your machine in an unknown state.

But your unsigned kext will load

Comment: It should read "disable", instead of "disbale".

Answer (score 0):

Your computer will always be able to boot with or without unsigned kexts (well, that is, assuming they don't provide some boot critical function like a SATA driver for your boot disk). Whether your computer will still be *useful* after booting without an unsigned kext of course depends on the nature of the extension.

At WWDC 2013, there was [a presentation about kext development](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2013/?id=707) that was very explicit: signing is supported and unchecked in 10.8, checked but not enforced in 10.9, and mandatory "in the future".

Signing requires a developer identity, and a developer identity requires an active Apple Developer Program membership.

So in answer to your question: No, you will not be able to develop and load kexts on upcoming versions of OS X without being an ADP member.

Apple has [a section on their developer website](https://developer.apple.com/support/code-signing/) dedicated to code signing topics.

Comment: So you mean that there is no point in me learning how to make kexts then? Would I be able to boot into Single User Mode and delete the kext if I cannot use my computer since it can still boot?

Comment: I wouldn't say there's no point. For $99 a year, you could easily recoup your costs in terms of increased productivity or a marketable product.

Comment: In terms of whether you could boot into Single User mode, I would say that it probably isn't required unless something about your kext is actually breaking your Mac. But to literally answer your question, yes; when you build a kext you have to specify how "critical" your kext is, and only certain levels of "critical" are loaded in Single User mode.

Comment: Suppose it isn't too bad cost. I worked out (if I did my maths correctly) if I released an application today and charged $0.99 for it and got 1 download a day I would have got my $99 back by the 21st of September. Not bad really. Only issue is I am not very creative. Maybe I could copy some ones idea and edit bit since there are loads of knock-offs in the App Store. Would that be ok to do? Also with xCode 7 you can now test your application without being a developer. This would be a good way to test!

Comment: @iProgram Testing your application never required a Developer account on Mac, restrictions applied only for iOS

Comment: @LaX I meant iOS. Sorry. Think the iOS market was bigger.

Comment: iOS development no longer requires a Developer account either. They just announced this. Note that now we're discussing apps and not kexts, like your original question...

Comment: "No, you will not be able to develop and load kexts on upcoming versions of OS X without being an ADP member." Other than the fact you cannot see into the future, the status quo is you cannot load unsigned kexts _by default_, but that restriction can itself be disabled in Yosemite, and thus far in El Capitan as well. Therefore that statement is untrue, at least without qualification.

Comment: @tubedogg Except that everything I wrote is qualified by statements from Apple. For instance, look at the WWDC presentation I linked.

Comment: At some point loading of unsigned kexts may be absolutely disabled by the system. As it currently stands, loading of unsigned kexts is able to be accomplished by changing a boot setting. Your statement about "upcoming versions" may be accurate, but those upcoming versions could be 10 years from now, or Apple could have meant "mandatory except for power users who change the boot setting". Simply stating "upcoming versions" in specific response to a question about El Capitan is misleading at best, especially since in the current beta you can still load them.